# Set builder notation for representing countably infinite cartesian products

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation, definition, cardinals

Let $X$ be an arbitrary set, are the following statements equivalent?

1. $$X^{\omega} = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z_+}} X$$
2. $$X^{\omega} = \left\{(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z_+}} \ | \ x_i \in X \right\}$$

i.e. is the following true :

$$X^{\omega} = \prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z_+}} X = \left\{(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z_+}} \ | \ x_i \in X \right\}$$

---

Is this a non-standard way of representing $X^{\omega}$ in set-builder notation? Are there better/cleaner more standard ways of representing $X^{\omega}$ in set builder notation?

Comment: If you define $A^B$ as the set of all functions from $B$ to $A$, and define $\prod_{i\in B}A_i$ as the set of all functions $f$ from $B$ to $\bigcup_{i\in B}A_i$ such that for all $i\in B$, $f(i)\in A_i$, then they look the same.

Comment: This all looks fine.  The product space is the space of sequences.

Comment: Since $\omega$ is the set of non-negative integers, you really ought to be using either $\omega$ or $\Bbb N$ (if $0\in\Bbb N$ for you) as the index set for your sequences, not $\Bbb Z^+$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Munkres uses $\mathbb{Z_+}$ all the way throughout his book *Topology: A First Course*, instead of $\omega$ or $\mathbb{N}$. I assumed it was the standard choice

Comment: @Perturbative: He uses some non-standard notation. (In particular, his use of $x\times y$ for a point of a Cartesian product $X\times Y$ instead of one of the usual ordered pair notations $\langle x,y\rangle$ or $(x,y)$ is atrocious.) Indexing sequences by $\Bbb Z_+$ is not uncommon, but in that case he ought to be writing $X^{\Bbb Z_+}$ or ${^{\Bbb Z_+}X}$. (${^AB}$ is a notation for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Quick question, would you recommend *Topology: A First Course* as a introductory book (for General Topology)? As you noted he does use some non-standard notation, and there are some other odd things I picked up. Like for example he defines and $\omega$-tuple before even defining $\omega$ or saying a word about ordinal numbers...

Comment: @Perturbative: Despite some notational peculiarities, it’s still one of the better undergraduate topology texts out there.